# JPA Development tools

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, apache-tomee

i use apache tomee, Java EE 6, servlet 3 and when i start the server tomee i have this errror:

```
Server TomEE Server at localhost at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

Comment: So? What's the question?

Comment: This entry contained slightly more than "I've got a problem", but only slightly. If you don't respect people on SO then don't be surprised people will not stand in long queues to help you.

Comment: Can you add the following information; how did you start TomEE (startup.sh or an IDE, if an IDE which IDE), how was the application deployed, what is the approximate size of the application, what JDK version

Answer (score 2):

This sort of situation has appeared in SO more than once.  Take a look at the console output, see if it tells you anything useful.  Read up on what others have done in response to the same issue, and try that.  If you run out of things to try, you can at least post the console results, so that others who understand better might have a chance of seeing what your problem is.  (Also post what you've tried and what the results were, both to give further information and to make it obvious that you've put some work into it.)

Comment: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
 at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)